# Mediator IPipeline not registered in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, mediator

I am trying to create a validation pipeline with mediator and fluent validation in ASP.NET, but the file is seem to me is not registered, so I need some help.

This is my validation pipeline:

```
using FluentValidation;
using MediatR;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public sealed class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse: JsonResult
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators) => _validators = validators;

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_validators.Any())
        {
            var context = new ValidationContext<TRequest>(request);
            var validationResults = await Task.WhenAll(_validators.Select(v => v.ValidateAsync(context, cancellationToken)));
            var failures = validationResults.SelectMany(r => r.Errors).Where(f => f != null).ToList();

            if (failures.Count != 0)
                throw new ValidationException("Validation Error", failures);
        }

        return await next();
    }
}
```

And this is my role validation this is apply

```
     RuleFor(x => x.Email)
       .NotEmpty()
       .NotNull()
       .EmailAddress();
```

This is my configuration

```
services.AddMediatR(config => config.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));                        
services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>));

services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

This is my error handling

```
using ecommerce_shared.Exceptions;
using ecommerce_shared.OperationResult.Base;
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ecommerce_shared.Middleware
{
    public class ErrorHandling : IMiddleware
    {
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var Result = new OperationResultBase<string>() { };

                switch (error)
                {
                    case ValidationException exception:
                        Result.Message = exception.Message;
                        Result.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.UnprocessableEntity;
                        Result.Errors = exception.Errors.Select(f => f.PropertyName + ":" + f.ErrorMessage).ToList(); ;
                        break;

                    case Exception exception:
                        Result.Message = exception.Message;
                        Result.StatusCode= (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        response.StatusCode= (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        break;
                }

                var errors = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Result);
                await response.WriteAsync(errors);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the request that I send:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://localhost:44318/Api/v1/UserAuth/Store' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json' \
  -d '{
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string",
  "email": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "cityId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6"
}'
```

And here is the response I get:

```
{
  "Result": null,
  "Message": "Validation failed: \r\n -- Email: 'Email' is not a valid email address. Severity: Error\r\n -- Email: 'Email' is not a valid email address. Severity: Error",
  "StatusCode": 422,
  "Errors": [
    "Email:'Email' is not a valid email address.",
    "Email:'Email' is not a valid email address.",
    "Email:'Email' is not a valid email address."
  ]
}
```